# UISearchController is looking wrong after touch

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, swift2

I added programmatically `UISearchController` into `UIViewController`, when `UIViewController` is loaded everything is good but when I touch `UISearchBar` in `UISearchController`, it move to bottom and it is looking wrong. I am adding UI element in code in the first time.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController = ({
        let controllerSearch = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controllerSearch.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)
        controllerSearch.delegate = self
        controllerSearch.searchBar.delegate = self
        controllerSearch.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Default
        controllerSearch.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controllerSearch.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controllerSearch.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controllerSearch.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.view.addSubview(controllerSearch.searchBar)
        return controllerSearch
    })()
}
```

Although I made that be console shows frame of `UISearchController` and it shows right result (0.0, 20.0, 320.0, 44.0) Please help me anyone.
Still I tried it but the results is the same.

```
  let frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)
  controllerSearch.searchBar.frame = frame
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I added the following element

```
@IBOutlet weak var navigationItemSearch: UINavigationItem!
```

And changed my `UISearchController`

```
   searchController = ({
        let controllerSearch = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controllerSearch.delegate = self
        controllerSearch.searchBar.delegate = self
        controllerSearch.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent
        controllerSearch.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controllerSearch.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false // false
        controllerSearch.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Default
        controllerSearch.searchResultsUpdater = self
        // placing
        controllerSearch.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        navigationItemSearch.titleView = controllerSearch.searchBar
        //
        controllerSearch.searchBar.spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingType.Yes
        controllerSearch.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None
        controllerSearch.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.WebSearch
        return controllerSearch
    })()
```